# City Engine - 3D zoning envelope & street orientation

Tags: cityengine

Is there a way to change the front & back angles that generate the 3D zoning envelope according to street orientation? Ideally there should be 6 cases which describe angular ranges and for each case a different angle is assigned to front,back and sides of the lot.

Would this require scripting? I am a complete novice in this and any help would be appreciated.